# Solving $\cos 3x = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

Tags: trigonometry

So I have this equation:

> $$\cos 3x = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

I get two answers: 
$$x = \frac{1}{12}(\pi + 8 \pi n) \qquad x = \frac{1}{12}(7 \pi + 8 \pi n )$$

What is $n$ in these cases?

Comment: I didn't know my cousin was involved in such equation.

You actually have infinitely many solutions to your equations. $n$ is just a integer you can choose to generate one solutions. Just set $n = 1$ or $n = -31$ and you will get a valid solution.

Comment: I'm not sure, but in many modern societies relations between cousins are frowned upon, which may include equality. (Sorry! Couldn't resist!)

Comment: If $\cos 3x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ then $\cos (3x+2k\pi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\implies3x=2m\pi\pm\dfrac\pi4=\dfrac\pi4(8m\pm1)$$ where $m$ is any integer

Now $\dfrac\pi4(8m-1)=\dfrac\pi4\{8(m-1)+7\}$